# problems with key Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code in which it is a table but they have made me some observations that I must make but I don't know how, what I'm doing is in a storybook in case they see it differently even a normal component, I think that would be the case

```
import React from "react"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"

export function Table({ header, content }) {
  return (
    <table className="text-sm">
      <thead className="h-3" style={{ background: "#F1F1F1" }}>
        <tr className="h-3 border-b" style={{ borderColor: "#E0E0E0" }}>
          {header.map((head, index) => (
            <th key={index} className="px-3 py-3 font-light text-left">
              {head}
            </th>
          ))}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      {content.map((row, index) => (
        <tr
          className="h-3 border-b"
          key={index}
          style={{ borderColor: "#E0E0E0" }}>
          {row.map((cell, i) => (
            <td className="px-3 py-3" key={i}>
              {cell}
            </td>
          ))}
        </tr>
      ))}
    </table>
  )
}

Table.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.string,
  header: PropTypes.array,
  content: PropTypes.array
}
export default Table
```

and I have made two observations which are:

1.You cannot use the index as a key for the component, it generates problems with the direct parent "row".

2.Indexes are not used as component "keys",

[image]

Comment: See https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Comment: here either instead of passing the index you can pass an unique value based on your content or header array of objects. Something like a head.property and row.id if its unique

Answer (score 1):

Why is it a bad idea to use indexes as keys?

> In practice, finding a key is usually not hard. The element you are going to display may already have a unique ID, so the key can just come from your data:
>
> {item.name}
> When that’s not the case, you can add a new ID property to your model or hash some parts of the content to generate a key. The key only has to be unique among its siblings, not globally unique.
>
> As a last resort, you can pass an item’s index in the array as a key. This can work well if the items are never reordered, but reorders will be slow.
>
> Reorders can also cause issues with component state when indexes are used as keys. Component instances are updated and reused based on their key. If the key is an index, moving an item changes it. As a result, component state for things like uncontrolled inputs can get mixed up and updated in unexpected ways.

You know, you can actually use a key on any component even if it's not a child in a list. Just try it, and change the key. What happens then? The component is <strike>rerendered</strike> destroyed and recreated from scratch. React uses keys to keep track of what have changed and if you reorder the components in a list, the key will change and hence React will consider that the component has changed in some way. So whenever your items can be reordered ina list, do not use indexes AT ALL! Do not combine them either. Usually, your items have ids, use them. Or use anything specific to each item that is guranteed to be unique (amongst siblings not globally). Use indexes as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your header, and row have unique properties such as `id`, if they do you can use them as keys, otherwise if they have any kind of differentiating values such as `name` you can combine with the `index` to make a key. Such as

```
<tr key={`${header.name}-${index}`} />
```

Which would make it unique most of the time.

Comment: It's not about unicity, it says not to use indexes so if you combine them and the elements are reordered, you still have the same problem.